# what do redirect in dnn6 whitout return value

Tags: c#, module, dotnetnuke

i working with dnn 6 and. when call

```
Response.Redirect(DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(), true)
```

all sessions which change value before i call that redirect not applied. example :

```
Session["currentPage"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["currentPage"]) + 1;  
Response.Redirect(DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(), true);
```

in this example `Session["currentPage"]` not Increase after redirect. please help me I realy do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you'll need to set the second parameter of `Response.Redirect` (`endResponse`) to `false` instead of `true`. This will not abort the execution of the current thread and hopefully leaves your session token intact.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i test it. please give me another solve.